# javascript - pass a value from parent to child window and within a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I've a form that contains several images. Once the user clicks whichever image a popup window with thumbnails is come up. Once he clicks whichever thumbnail, the source image in the parent window needs to replaced according the user selection (swapping the original image). The following script works fine for one image only since **logo1** and **placeHolder1** variables are hard coded. How can I send the image id from the parent window to the popup window, so the following will be dynamic?

editPage.editForm.**logo1**.value = oName

editPage. **placeHolder1**.src = " images/user/" + oName;

BTW, the images name’s and id’s in the main window subject to be changed according the form template.

**template.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function logoWin() {
window.open('logos.php','logos','height=500,width=700,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
}
</script>

<form action="" id="editForm" name="editForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src=”images/user/logo1.jpg” name="placeHolder1" id="placeHolder1" onclick='logoWin()'>
<img src=”images/user/logo2.jpg” name="placeHolder2" id="placeHolder2" onclick='logoWin()'>
<img src=”images/user/logo3.jpg” name="placeHolder3" id="placeHolder3" onclick='logoWin()'>

<input type="hidden" name="logo1" value="<?php echo $main_logo1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="logo2" value="<?php echo $main_logo2; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="logo3" value="<?php echo $main_logo3; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save">
</form>
```

**logos.php**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getFile(oImg){
        editPage = eval(window.opener.document)
        oSrc = oImg.src;
        lastSlash = oSrc.lastIndexOf('/');
        oName = oSrc.substr(lastSlash+1);
        editPage.editForm.logo1.value = oName
        editPage. placeHolder1.src = " images/user/" + oName;
        this.close()
    }
    </script>   

[php loop]
<img src='images/user/".$row->img_file_name."' onclick='getFile(this)'>
<img src='images/user/".$row->img_file_name."' onclick='getFile(this)'>
<img src='images/user/".$row->img_file_name."' onclick='getFile(this)'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using

```
eval(window.opener.document);
```

You can use

```
var editPage = window.opener.document;
```

You can pass the id with `url` of the page as given below

```
function logoWin(id) {
    window.open('logos.php?id='+id,'logos','height=500,...');
}
```

Pass the `id` as function paarameter, like (`logoWin(1)`, `logoWin(2)`) as given below

```
<img src=”images/user/logo1.jpg” name="placeHolder1" id="placeHolder1" onclick='logoWin(1)'>
<img src=”images/user/logo2.jpg” name="placeHolder2" id="placeHolder2" onclick='logoWin(2)'>
```

In your `logos.php` file, get it id using

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // it could be 1 or 2 or 3 and so on
```

Then, you can use it as `JavaScript` variable like

```
function getFile(oImg){
    var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
    editPage = eval(window.opener.document);
    oSrc = oImg.src;
    lastSlash = oSrc.lastIndexOf('/');
    oName = oSrc.substr(lastSlash+1);
    var logo = 'logo'+id, placeHolder = 'placeHolder'+id;
    editPage.editForm[logo].value = oName;
    editPage[placeHolder].src = " images/user/" + oName;
    this.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message: Invalid left-hand side in assignment for `editPage.editForm.logo+id.value = oName` - any idea?

Comment: I get: `Cannot set property 'value' of undefined` when I added: `var = oName;` I got: `getFile is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, check the `getFile()` function again, `var logo = 'logo'+id, placeHolder = 'placeHolder'+id;`.

Comment: Just a quick question: this line
`<img src='images/user/".$row->img_file_name."' onclick='getFile(this)'>` held the bigger image, which is good when swapping, but can I send this bigger image and **show its thumbnail**? Meaning something like this:
`<img src='images/user/".$row->thumbnail."' onclick='getFile(".$row->img_file_name.")'>`

Comment: Yes, you can, just use the bigger image url

Comment: For some reason `editPage.editForm[logo].value = oName;` not insert the value for hidden fields but for text type only. Any idea?